# Google Web Font is not being used in Angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I have an Angular project setup with the angular-cli. I'd like to bundle Roboto font with my website so the way I do it is I declare it in my styles.scss

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

// Set Global Font
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
```

However, it seems like the font anyway defaults to sans-serif instead of Roboto. I tried adding a link inside index.html, the same effect.

P.S. not sure if related, but I also add Material Icons

```
// Import Material Icons
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'),
       local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
       url('../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

in the very same file, could this somehow have an effect on the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're working on the @angular/cli project, I doubt that links in the .scss file works.

Install roboto-fontface through npm and link it in the styles array of angular-cli.json

```
npm install roboto-fontface --save
```

In the angular-cli.json styles array 'apps[0].styles' add the following

```
    "styles": [
      ...
      "../node_modules/roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css"
      ...
    ]
```

And, `npm start` and try out the styles

Comment: It seems like you solution is working. Font actually changes now when I disable Roboto font-family but why is it no working with online CDN?

Comment: @NikkiKononov Valid question. I am assuming that it's something with the CLI compiler. The build fails when you add the CDN there in the styles tag.
And, as I know this is the recommended way of doing it. Make sure you keep the update with the cli releases. things are changing rapidly

Comment: You can add the material design icons following the same way @NikkiKononov

Comment: Yes I am looking closely at changes made. That's why I opted to use everything offline :) thanks for the help. Marked as valid answer.

Comment: getting error of "WARNING in Invalid font values at 15949:4. Ignoring."
In the ng build --prod

Comment: Is there an official npm package for the roboto font from google?

Comment: @Mustafa Not sure about google's. But, check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/roboto-fontface
If the above doesn't work or give any error then it's recommended to add the downloaded fonts to the assets folder and import it and do the configs

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

**Note!** Material Icons are also hosted on Google fonts (no need for a local version)

```
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Material+Icons');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
body:after {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: 'star';
}
```

Comment: With angular-cli I try to host everything locally but for the sake of experiment I tried load fonts both locally and via google web fonts, either way, seems like font family defaults to sans-serif when I check it. Like if I remove Roboto font via Google Dev Tools the text font doesn't change.

Comment: Check my answer and try it out. It should work since I am using the same methodology in my app and luckily I am using roboto @NikkiKononov

Comment: @SaiyaffFarouk yea it seems like I mixed up people here :D your solution does indeed work, using Roboto locally. The question then why does CDN refuse to work?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the issue of google fonts not being applied. Following way worked without npm install of the fonts by placing fonts link with style within head of index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Markazi+Text:wght@450" />

<style>
  * {
    font-family: 'Markazi Text';
    font-weight: 400;
  }
</style>
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2